# CircleCI: Can sections or phases of the build test deploy process be conditional

Tags: circleci

I currently have a circle.yml with build, test and deploy sections.  I would like to parameterize the build to run nightly automation similar to this link https://circleci.com/docs/1.0/nightly-builds/

When running nightly automation I would like to avoid running the deploy section all together.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, no, not yet at least. However, within the phase, you can get your desired outcome.

When running a nightly build, which I assume means you're using the CircleCI API, make sure to pass some sort of environment variable. Something like `BUILD_TYPE=nightly` would work.

Then, in the deployment section for that branch (I assume master here?), use Bash to check if the variable exists/is set to what you expect. If so, do nothing. If not, run the deployment command.

An example:

```
deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - |
        if [[ $BUILD_TYPE == "nightly" ]]; then
          echo "Skipping deployment"
        else
          rsync -va --delete /myapp/ user@myserver.net:/myapp
        fi
```